# assembly lang 8085 .. how to find even/odd parity

Tags: assembly, parity, 8085

I have the following code to count the number of 1s and save it to reg B. I need to modify it to find if the parity is even or odd...

```
LXI H, var1
MVI B, 00H
MVI D, 00H
MVI C, 08H
MOV A, M

LOOP: RAR
JNC SKIP
INR B
SKIP: DCR C
JNZ LOOP

HLT

var1: db 72
```

Comment: Which value are you trying to determine the parity of?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An even parity means that there's an even number of bits set in an octet. According to this brief introduction to [Intel 8085 architecture](http://www.cpu-world.com/Arch/8085.html):

> Flag is an 8-bit register containing 5 1-bit flags:
>    - Sign - set if the most significant bit of the result is set.
>    - Zero - set if the result is zero.
>    - Auxiliary carry - set if there was a carry out from bit 3 to bit 4 of the result.
>    - ***Parity*** - set if the parity (the number of set bits in the result) is even.
>    - Carry - set if there was a carry during addition, or borrow during subtraction/comparison.

The parity flag can be most easily tested with conditional branches ([link to source](http://engeletrica.sobral.ufc.br/professores/marcelo/Micro/8085_is_details.pdf))

```
JPE label;   // Jump if parity is Even 
JPO label;   // or jump if parity is Odd
```

The flag is set by most arithmetic and logical instructions that deal with a single output registers. Counter-examples are *MOV*, and *CMP*, which doesn't store a result. Arithmetic operations (*INX*, *DEX* etc.) that modify a register pair in turn do not have an unambiguous result.

Comment: That's true, but you can't just blindly use the parity bit - only certain operations set it.

Comment: +1 - but be sure to OR the value with itself first. As in `ORA A`. Then check the parity bit with `JPE` or `JPO`

Answer (score 4):

With `B` holding the count of set bits in the input: just bitwise `AND` register `B` with the value `1`. If the result is `1`, it's odd parity. If the result is `0`, it's even parity. That's because even numbers always have `0` in the least significant bit, odd numbers always have `1`.

Accessing *very* vague memories of 8080-class assembly, but I think it would be something like:

```
          MOV      A, B
          ANI      01H
          JZ       par_even
par_odd   ; parity is odd here, work your magic
          JMP      par_done

par_even  ; parity is even here, work other magic

par_done  ; carry on processing here
```

For example, the value `72` that you're using, is `64 + 8` or binary `01001000`.

So, assuming your bit counting code works correctly, register `B` will be set to two, or `00000010`. ANDing that with `00000001` gives you 0, hence even parity.

Alternatively, the value `254`, or `11111110` would set register `B` to `7`, or `00000111`. ANDing that with `00000001` gives `1`, hence odd parity.

You can also use something like:

```
ANA    A
JPE    par_even
```

where A is the *value* rather than the count of 1-bits.

The reason you *may* need the ANA is to ensure the parity flag is set based on the contents of the accumulator. Only certain operations set the flags and ANDing the accumulator with itself will leave it untouched but set the P, S and Z flags based on it.

Comment: @Aki, you stated that B is the _number_ of 1-bits in the value you're checking, _not_ the value itself. The parity of that value _is_ whether or not the 1-bit count is even, which is decided totally by the least significant bit of the count. You need to re-read the answer. I wasn't stating that the LSB was the parity bit.

Comment: @Jim, I suggest you reread the question and answer. When you count the 1bits in that number, as per the original code, you end up with 3, which is 00000011 - the LSB is SET hence odd parity.

Comment: Ahhh ... now I see. I downvoted and shouldn't have. For some reason it won't let me reverse my vote unless the answer is edited.

Comment: Thanks for correcting. It's the correct answer to a wrong question. (Changed the parity of my vote accordingly)